# Sending Data over SPI in DMA mode on the stm32MP1

Tags: c, stm32

I am trying to send data Over SPI on DMA mode on the STM32MP157C-DK2 board.
the goal is to send data from GPIO_PIN_8 to GPIO_PIN_9 and check of they are the same.

I tried to use the HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA function but i am not really sure how does it work. It takes the transmit buffer and receive buffer as an input. but how to tell the function that i want to send from pin 8(MOSI) to pin 9 (MISO). and how to see and display the data i am sending and to check that it is received correctly on the other pin.

Do i have to give the transmit receive function the GPIOS addresses instead of the TX and RX Buffer?. but how to tell the function the data i want to send.

I configured the GPIOS and the SPI5 as follows:

```
#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define GPIOF_OutPut_Data   (0x40010028)
#define GPIOF_Input_Data    (0x44009000)+(0x30)
 enum
{
    TRANSFER_WAIT,
    TRANSFER_COMPLETE,
    TRANSFER_ERROR
};       
/* Buffer used for transmission */
uint8_t aTxBuffer[] = "****SPI Message based on DMA ****";
/* Buffer used for reception */
uint8_t aRxBuffer[BUFSIZE];
/* transfer state */
__IO uint32_t wTransferState = TRANSFER_WAIT;
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi5;
        DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_spi5_tx;
        DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_spi5_rx;
    void SystemClock_Config(void);
    static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
    static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
    static void MX_IPCC_Init(void);
    static void MX_SPI5_Init(void);
    static uint16_t Buffercmp(uint8_t *pBuffer1, uint8_t *pBuffer2, uint16_t BufferLength);
    int main(void)
    {
     MX_GPIO_Init();
      MX_DMA_Init();
      MX_SPI5_Init();
    /**SPI5 GPIO Configuration
      PH6     ------> SPI5_SCK
      PF8     ------> SPI5_MISO
      PF9     ------> SPI5_MOSI
      */
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI5;
      // From Alternate Function Table from Data-sheet for Port F
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);
          //Transmit and Receive Data over SPI in DMA Mode

         if(HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA(&hspi5, (uint8_t*)aTxBuffer, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer, BUFSIZE) != HAL_OK)
           {
             /* Transfer error in transmission process */
             printf("Entered Transmit Receive DMA Mode");
             Error_Handler();
           }

           /*##-2- Wait for the end of the transfer ###################################*/
           /*  Before starting a new communication transfer, you must wait the callback call
               to get the transfer complete confirmation or an error detection.
               This code is just waiting till the end of the
               transfer, but application may perform other tasks while transfer operation
               is ongoing. */
           while (wTransferState == TRANSFER_WAIT)
           {
           }

           switch(wTransferState)
           {
             case TRANSFER_COMPLETE :
               /*##-3- Compare the sent and received buffers ##############################*/
               if(Buffercmp((uint8_t*)aTxBuffer, (uint8_t*)aRxBuffer, BUFSIZE))
                   //if buffers are identical, the return value should be 0, otherwise go to Error handler
               {
                 /* Processing Error */

                   Error_Handler();
               }
             break;
             default :
               Error_Handler();
             break;
           }
    }
    static void MX_SPI5_Init(void)
    {

      /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI5_Init 0 */

      /* USER CODE END SPI5_Init 0 */

      /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI5_Init 1 */

      /* USER CODE END SPI5_Init 1 */
      /* SPI5 parameter configuration*/
      hspi5.Instance = SPI5;
      hspi5.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
      hspi5.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
      hspi5.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT;
      hspi5.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
      hspi5.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
      hspi5.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
      hspi5.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_64;
      hspi5.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
      hspi5.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
      hspi5.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
      hspi5.Init.CRCPolynomial = 0x0;
      hspi5.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_ENABLE;
      hspi5.Init.NSSPolarity = SPI_NSS_POLARITY_LOW;
      hspi5.Init.FifoThreshold = SPI_FIFO_THRESHOLD_01DATA;
      hspi5.Init.TxCRCInitializationPattern = SPI_CRC_INITIALIZATION_ALL_ZERO_PATTERN;
      hspi5.Init.RxCRCInitializationPattern = SPI_CRC_INITIALIZATION_ALL_ZERO_PATTERN;
      hspi5.Init.MasterSSIdleness = SPI_MASTER_SS_IDLENESS_00CYCLE;
      hspi5.Init.MasterInterDataIdleness = SPI_MASTER_INTERDATA_IDLENESS_00CYCLE;
      hspi5.Init.MasterReceiverAutoSusp = SPI_MASTER_RX_AUTOSUSP_DISABLE;
      hspi5.Init.MasterKeepIOState = SPI_MASTER_KEEP_IO_STATE_DISABLE;
      hspi5.Init.IOSwap = SPI_IO_SWAP_DISABLE;
      if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi5) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI5_Init 2 */

      /* USER CODE END SPI5_Init 2 */

    }
    void HAL_SPI_ErrorCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
    {
      wTransferState = TRANSFER_ERROR;
    }

    /**
      * @brief  Compares two buffers.
      * @param  pBuffer1, pBuffer2: buffers to be compared.
      * @param  BufferLength: buffer's length
      * @retval 0  : pBuffer1 identical to pBuffer2
      *         >0 : pBuffer1 differs from pBuffer2
      */
    static uint16_t Buffercmp(uint8_t* pBuffer1, uint8_t* pBuffer2, uint16_t BufferLength)
    {
      while (BufferLength--)
      {
        if((*pBuffer1) != *pBuffer2)
        {
          return BufferLength;
        }
        pBuffer1++;
        pBuffer2++;
      }

      return 0;
    }

    void Error_Handler(void)
    {
      /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
      /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
    printf("No Transfer of Data");
      while(1)
         {
             setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
             fprintf(stdout, "LED7 is blinking");
             Delay_wait(0x5000000);
             HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_7);

         }
      /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
    }
```